# How does yield behave when we pass it an action in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have the following code:

**Component template**

```
{{#link-to "user.profile" account.id disabled=user.online}}
    {{yield}}
{{/link-to}}
```

**Template**

```
{{#my-component data=x}}
    <button> MY BUTTON </button>
{{/my-component}}
```

I use the component in different templates and I'd like the yielded elements to have an action. I've read you can use it like this but I can't really grasp the behaviour.

```
{{#link-to "user.profile" account.id disabled=user.online}}
    {{yield (action "showModal")}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here its usage:

```
{{#my-component as |act|}}
    <button onclick={{action act}}>Button</button>
{{/my-component}}
```

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/29bf5c879b812cc9e079d2f35cb4e5e0?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) is  working twiddle.

To understand more: here is a [good blog post](http://www.serabe.com/2016/02/29/the-path-to-contextual-components-understanding-positional-parameters/). This is a one of the three posts of the writer about contextual components.